# apns service conformation procedure

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

once i submitted app to app store by enabling push notifications for that particular app id and i generated the certificate fro production and i saved in my server.

now i want to test my push notifications are working or not,now my doubt is if i use the same bundle id for my another project and keeping the same certificate which i generated for production apns on my server. if i send notifications now to that certificate will notifications work or won't  work.  i was confused totally after having lot of discussion with my friend.

in my point of view they won't work,but i am unable to clarify him clearly,let me know what is process once we send a notification to apple server by using particular certificate. whether it looks fro bundle identifiers or any thing

thankyou......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of push notification is that your server send message with the attachment of device token you added in the server end.

On apple server apple fetch the device token and send the message to the device token you send.

Now when the message received in iPhone, iphone check the bundle identifier that was registered with the certificate you have created at server level while enabling push notification.

And if that identifier matches with any of the app you have in your iPhone whether it`s the same app you have registered your push or other. It will only check the bundle identifier and show the notification on your device.

Now both the production and developer certificates are different so it will not show the notification if you are sending push from certificates generated with developer mode and checking on production application.

Regards
Abhishek Goyal

Comment: tahnk you for quick reply, and what abot cerificate we are placing in server,what information does certificate contatin,why notifications are not working with out certificate, in above process there is no discusssion about certificate na

Comment: how can i mainatin badge number for push notificaions

Comment: certificate only contains the information about the application to which the push notification belongs to.

Comment: you can maintain the badge number by adding an extra field in the user table for the read notification. Whenever user open application or read the notification you have to set the value of that field to 0 and if not you have to increase that number each time you are sending the notification to that particular user. This is the way what`s app and other application manage the badge number in iphone apps

Comment: do u mean if i placed wrong certificate correct device token in my server,if i send the notifiaction it will reach the applesrver,and sends notifications to that device and it will check for that identifier and sends the notification, then where it ckecks the certificate is of production or development type?

Comment: if your certificate is wrong then it will not able to send the push notification ti any of the device. 

Apple has two servers one is for development and one is for production.

Comment: so depend on certificate it will go to particular server and it contain bundle identifier and does it contain any apple credentials,other wise how applw will know our certificate is wrong or expired, can i see the certificate information like as provisoining profile by editing with particular application

Comment: it will always go to apple server. Apple server will check the certificate and check its valid or not. If its valid then only it allow to send the notification.
The process is like first a request is made to the apple server using our certificate which is the combination of pushnotification ssl and private key chain certificate. That contains the info about the app and its own. After successful connection with the apple server it will send the notification. So our own server sends the message and the device token to the apple server and apple server sends the message to the particular device.